# PHP lastInsertId() returns 0 in Database class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm trying to create database class for sql queries.

I'm able to basic crud stuff but when I add something to database `lastInsertId()` returns 0

db connection in mysql class

```
public function connect() {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",
            $this->db_username,$this->db_password);
    }
```

my save method in database class

```
public function save()
    {
        $values = [];
        $keys = [];
        $marks = [];

        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
            array_push($keys, $key);
            array_push($marks, '?');
            array_push($values, $value);
            $this->__unset($key);
        }
        $keys = implode(',', $keys);
        $marks = implode(',', $marks);
        try {
            $query = $this->connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO $this->table ($keys) VALUES ($marks)");
            $query->execute($values);

            return $this->connect()->lastInsertId();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

I'm using this class, it saves data to database succesfuly but still returns 0

```
$query = new Database('table');
$query->foo = "bar";
$data = $query->save();

echo $data;
// 0
```

What am I missing in here ? How can I fix that ?

Comment: Whenever you call `$this->connect()` your're creating a new connection along with a clean query history i.e.  no last insert id being remembered. Use some sort of singleton. Alternatively the last inserted id is `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table`

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: @apokryfos But I have not close the connection yet

Comment: You're not properly escaping `$keys` or the table name. These *must* be quoted like MySQL identifiers.

Comment: @tadman I just want to improve my skills .  I like to use eloquant, probably that's why I'm trying to do similar thing

Comment: Each time you do `new PDO` you are creating a new connection. If you don't store it in a variable then you lose the reference to the connection. The connection remains open but you have no means to use it again and you end up making a new one

Comment: Call connect only once. Store that in a var, like $db. Then use $db->prepare/execute/lastInsertId. You're creating a new connectionneach time you call connect.

Comment: Why `$keys` need to be escape. I thought values are important

Comment: From an academic perspective, sure, I'd encourage you to learn, but if this is for production code I'd steer away from this as it's going to be nothing but trouble. Be careful, extremely careful, even bordering on paranoid, when writing code like this. Have exhaustive unit tests that explore all the edge cases with column names like `table` and increasingly ridiculous table names like `➨My Fancy Table Full Of Things☜` (yes, UTF-8 is allowed!), to be sure you've got it right.

Comment: @apokryfos ohh I didin't know that, thank you for informing me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new connection object each time you call `connect`, so you need to store the original call in a variable for reuse later. See below:

```
$query = $this->connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO $this->table ($keys) VALUES ($marks)");
$query->execute($values);
return $query->lastInsertId(); // Here, reuse the var, rather than create new
```

**EDIT** - I missed the chaining of methods. In this case, its more beneficial to split them out. See below:

```
$query = 'SELECT....';
$db = $this->connect();
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
// bind params here
$stmt->execute();
$lastId = $db->lastInsertId();
```

You need to run `lastInsertId` against the connection, not the prepared statement.

Comment: it throws this error ` Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId()`